# EOFError Opening/Reading Pickled File

Tags: python, pickle, readfile

so I have a pickled file that I would like to read and display the data from. I've never worked with pickled files before, but from a little research I found simple commands that should open it properly. Unfortunately I receive some errors that I will display below:

```
import pickle

f = open("1965.pkl")

here = pickle.load(f)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-43273f8d751b>", line 1, in <module>
    here = pickle.load(f)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
    raise EOFError

EOFError
```

Not really sure what this issue is since the EOFError doesn't give its usual description.

Any help is a big thanks!

Comment: You forgot to open file, so you can't read from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
   here = pickle.load(open("1965.pkl", 'rb'))
```

[ Edit ]:

Or you wrote to pickle with wrong flag.

For writing you should use 'wb'; for reading 'rb'